# Dynamically generate view definition for odbc cosmos data source

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

There is requirement that where my 3rd party application needs to connect with cosmos DB. So I setup an ODBC connection for COSMOS via ODBC Cosmos Driver. In my cosmos account containers are dynamically generated.
Problem is in some cases I am not be able to query some columns via ODBC. These are not nested properties in document.

I also tried one workaround solution by going in Schema Editor > Schema Definition > View Definition > Add New view.By this i am able to get the data.
But as said my containers are dynamically generated, so how can i add view definition dynamically to containers.

Comment: Why do you need to use ODBC to connect to Cosmos? Can you use something else?

Comment: @MarkBrown My 3rd party application can only connect via ODBC.

Comment: I see. So unfortunately I do not see how this would work where you are dynamically creating new containers. Apologies I can't think of a workaround here.